# Requiring module with karma not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, raphael, karma-mocha

I create a dev Javascript environment using TDD by using node, jake, karma, chai and browserify. Everything works fine, tests run green. Now I want to use Raphael to draw SVGs. I installed raphael `npm install raphael` to my local node environment (not globally). Requiring

```
var raphael = require("node-raphael")
```

Whenever I require it in my `app.js` file, it throws an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module 'raphael' from '../Project/src/javascript/app.js'
```

Just for testing I required it in my jakefile which is in my Project directory. There, requiring works fine. But using the Raphael functions also does not work.

node modules are also placed in the Project dir. "Project/node-modules/raphael"

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `raphael`, but from looking at npmjs.com there are two different modules:  `raphael` and `node-raphael`. You have installed `raphael`, but you are requiring `node-raphael`. So, you either need to install `node-raphael`:

`npm install node-raphael`

or require `raphael` in your code:

`var raphael = require("raphael")`

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/raphael and https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-raphael.

Comment: Hi Jeff, that's what I tried and it works for files I have not included for testing. But trying to require raphael within my specs to use it for creating tests, karma tells me it can't find this module. 

Think that's because I somehow need an adapter to use it with karma. Other libs, e.g. "chai" do have something like that. Adding it as a framework to the karma.conf.js works fine and without any trouble.

In general I am only looking for a way to create complex svgs using a testing framework. But I also don't know how to get other libs like "snap.svg" running with karma.